# How to debug remote chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I run chrome with:

```
chrome.exe ---remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Then I open chrome (or firefox) with :

```
http://localhost:9222 or http://127.0.0.1:9222
```

and these pages just never load as if nothing were running on that port

I also tried different ports.

Comment: It means the port is 1) used by another app so you need to [find an open port](https://www.google.com/search?q=find+an+open+port) or 2) you didn't exit all chrome processes which you can do by clicking Exit in the browser menu or in task manager's advanced view.

Comment: I tried many different ports. I restarted the PC as well.

Comment: Use [tcpview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to verify the port is free before running Chrome and to see if it's occupied by chrome afterwards,

Comment: Also, you have three hyphens in the command line, but it should have just two.